# replacing list with user input list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

hi i'm trying to make a function that takes a 20 element list inputted by a user and replaces an existing one with the same amount of elements. it works, but the first and last elements of the old list continue to be the same. how can i make the old list the exact same as the new one?
here's my code:

```
old_list = []
for integer in range(20):
    old_list.append(integer)

def inputNewList(old_list):
    new_list = [int(integer) for integer in input("Enter 20 integers: ").split(maxsplit=20)[:20]]
    print(new_list)
    old_list[integer] = new_list[integer]
    print(old_list)

inputNewList(old_list)
```

here's how the output looks like

```
Enter 20 integers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20]
```

i'm assuming something is wrong with the range of both.

Comment: If you want to set the whole content of `old_list` to the content of `new_list` you could do `old_list[:] = new_list`. If that's not what you want to do, then I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: yuppp this is exactly what i needed. thanks a lot!